# Two largest contiguous subarray

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I'm currently doing a problem that's similar to the maximum contiguous sub-array problem. However, instead of finding just one contiguous sub-array, I can find up to two non-overlapping contiguous subarrays.

For instance for the test case below, the answer is 20 since we can take everything but -20.

```
5 3 -20 4 8
```

To do this, I implemented the following code:

```
long long n, nums[500500], dp[500500][2][3];

long long best(int numsLeft, int beenTaking, int arrLeft) {
    if (arrLeft < 0 || numsLeft < 0) return 0;

    if (dp[numsLeft][beenTaking][arrLeft] != -1)
        return dp[numsLeft][beenTaking][arrLeft];

    if (beenTaking) {
        // continue Taking
        long long c1 = best(numsLeft - 1, beenTaking, arrLeft) + nums[numsLeft];
        // stop Taking
        long long c2 = best(numsLeft - 1, 0, arrLeft);

        return dp[numsLeft][beenTaking][arrLeft] = max(c1, c2);
    } else {
        // continue not Taking
        long long c1 = best(numsLeft - 1, beenTaking, arrLeft);
        // start Taking
        long long c2 = best(numsLeft - 1, 1, arrLeft - 1) + nums[numsLeft];

        return dp[numsLeft][beenTaking][arrLeft] = max(c1,c2);
    }
}
```

This is the function call:

```
cout << best(n - 1, 0, 2) << endl;
```

The dp array has been -1 filled before the function call. The nums array contain n elements and is zero-indexed.

Ideone.com link is this: http://ideone.com/P5PB7h

While my code does work for the sample test-case shown above, it fails for some other test-cases (that are not available to me). Are there any edge cases that are not being caught by my code? Where am I going wrong? Thank you for the help.

I tried coming up with a few such edge cases, but am unable to do so.

Comment: sorry you have to get test input with which code fails

Comment: `long long n, nums[500500], dp[500500][2][3];` -- This is 22 Megabytes of static storage being taken up (if `sizeof(long long)` ==8), maybe stack space depending on where these are declared.  Consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: *It fails for some other test-cases (that are not available to me)* -- In the real world, we have the test cases where are programs supposedly fail.

Comment: Also, you wrote a recursive solution.  How do you know if you haven't got a stack overflow from recursing too deeply?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm just starting out with algorithmic programming, and am now only getting the hang of it. I'm also trying to figure out the testcases for which my program fails. I tried reducing the memory limit (so that the program will only fail for large test cases), but it gives the wrong answer even for smaller test cases.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan Is it that the answer is wrong, or you get a timeout or other error?  Even for small input, a recursive solution with a bug or two can causes issues due to infinite recursion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wrong Answer. It does not exceed memory limit nor time limit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie By small input, I'm referring to about fifty numbers.

Comment: Is there something wrong with good old Kadane algorithm? It sees all contiguous subarrays in process, can select the two largest.

Comment: @n.m. Since Kadane's algorithm keep the max-sum-so-far, and I pick the two largest sums in the list, wouldn't there be a high chance of overlapping sub-arrays? The two sub-arrays I pick mustn't overlap. Or do I need to treat Kadane's algorithm differently?

Comment: You only need to modify it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on the following lines:

```
if (beenTaking) {
    // continue Taking
    long long c1 = best(numsLeft - 1, beenTaking, arrLeft) + nums[numsLeft];
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Adding `best(numsLeft - 1, 1, arrLeft)` without decrementing arrLeft implies that the "best" results from the first `numsLeft - 1` values in `nums[]` happens at the end of nums[] (at index `numsLeft - 1`). This may not be true.

The code will therefore likely fail when there are more than 2 positive ranges separated by negative values.

Also, the `dp` array should be initialized to something clearly out of range, like LLONG_MIN, rather than -1, which could be a legitimate sum.

Comment: I removed the memoization altogether for the purpose of debugging, and changed `arrLeft` to `arrLeft - 1`, but am now getting wrong answers for even simple cases like `5 5 5 -5 5 5`
I'm getting 15 when the answer should be 25 (the original code gives the right answer).

Comment: You asked what is the edge case(s) that you missed. That's what I was trying to answer. I didn't say (or know yet) what the correct solution should be based on your code. But if you debug in the direction, and changed the initialization to LLONG_MIN, it should be possible to find it.